# sql - Extract a date from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `description` in my table with string value like this

```
"PK Event System Time: 31 January 2019 02:09  OK TO RIGOUR till 08:00 on Thursday Morning"
```

I need to extract the date part from this in SQL Server.

Expected output:

```
 31 January 2019 02:09
```

Comment: What have you tried? More than one example would be nice.

Comment: are you allowed to create custom functions ?

Comment: My guess is this is not likely going to work very well for you. Given the column name "description" I would assume this is user entered data. So you are going to have all kinds of formats, spelling errors and invalid dates. At best you might be able to extract some of this data.

Comment: if everything is static use this, SELECT SUBSTRING('PK Event System Time: 31 January 2019 02:09  OK TO RIGOUR till 08:00 on Thursday Morning', 23, 23) AS description;

Comment: @CoderMal that won't work. Not all month names are the same length. ;)

Comment: "OK TO RIGOUR till" this String always present ?

Answer (score 3):

According to what you provide, you can simply use `CHARINDEX()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions as:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(
       SUBSTRING(V, 
                 CHARINDEX(':', V)+2, 
                 CHARINDEX(':', V, CHARINDEX(':', V)+2) - CHARINDEX(':', V)+2
                ) AS DATETIME)
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('PK Event System Time: 31 January 2019 02:09  OK TO RIGOUR till 08:00 on Thursday Morning'),
  ('Whatever: 01 Jun 2012 09:02  OK TO RIGOUR')
) T(V)
```

Note that the datetime should be always after ":". If it's not the case then please provide a good sample data.

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f9da9ff2a4e18f9419064280c451b94)**</kbd>

Comment: @AasimKhan Please read and follow [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I cannot up vote as I have less reputation. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for your one example. I'm depending on the date starting after the first colon in the text string and then the time containing the second occurrence of a colon to locate the end of the date and time.

```
With TestValues AS
(
SELECT V.TextValue
FROM (VALUES
        ('PK Event System Time: 31 January 2019 02:09  OK TO RIGOUR till 08:00 on Thursday Morning')
     ) V(TextValue)

)
SELECT T.TextValue, TRY_CAST(DateString.DateString AS datetime) AS DateTimeVersion
FROM TestValues AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',T.TextValue),0) + 2 AS N) AS DateStart
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',T.TextValue,DateStart.N),0) + 3 AS N) AS DateEnd
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(T.TextValue,DateStart.N,DateEnd.N - DateStart.N) AS DateString) AS DateString
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried but it is throwing error on substring --- "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." It might be while substracting the end - start.

Comment: What text value are you testing it against?

Comment: I've added in a fix for failed matches that was probably causing the error but it still suggests you're feeding it text values that don't match the pattern in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING.

If "OK TO RIGOUR till" this String always present in your data then you check below query

```
select Trim( SUBSTRING(tbl.str, CHARINDEX(':',tbl.str) + 2 , (CHARINDEX('OK',tbl.str))  - (CHARINDEX(':',tbl.str) + 2))) from (SELECT V.str
FROM (VALUES
        ('PK Event System Time: 31 January 2019 02:09  OK TO RIGOUR till 08:00 on Thursday Morning')
     ) V(str)

  )tbl
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/59559

Comment: No. it won't be the same. Thank you anyway :) I got the solution.